# Check if some particular months fall between two date columns of data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a vector of month values, `months = 5:10` (for May - October) and I have a `data.table` with two date columns. I want to remove all rows where the date range specified by these two columns does not span (including the two start and end dates themselves) any of the months in the vector. So I want to keep a row if any of the months falls between these two dates. If anyone can provide some help with this it would be great!

```
df
start       end
2018-06-01  2019-05-31
2018-06-04  2019-05-31
2018-06-05  2019-05-31
2018-07-20  2019-05-31
2018-11-01  2019-04-30
2019-01-01  2019-05-31
2019-04-01  2019-05-31
2019-05-01  2019-05-31
2019-06-01  2019-10-31
2019-06-01  2020-05-31
2019-11-01  2020-04-30
2020-05-01  2020-05-31
```

So for this example, these two rows should be the ones that are removed from the table:

```
df
start       end
2018-11-01  2019-04-30
2019-11-01  2020-04-30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible `data.table` approach:

```
df[
    df[, {
            #get all months between dates
            m <- seq((year(start)-1L)*12L + month(start), 
                (year(end)-1L)*12L + month(end)) %% 12L
            replace(m, m==0L, 12L)
        }, 
        by=.(rn=df[, seq_len(.N)])][
            #filter for rows with required months by using a join
            .(V1=months), on=.(V1), sort(unique(rn))]
]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
months <- 5:10
df <- fread("start       end
2018-06-01  2019-05-31
2018-06-04  2019-05-31
2018-06-05  2019-05-31
2018-07-20  2019-05-31
2018-11-01  2019-04-30
2019-01-01  2019-05-31
2019-04-01  2019-05-31
2019-05-01  2019-05-31
2019-06-01  2019-10-31
2019-06-01  2020-05-31
2019-11-01  2020-04-30
2020-05-01  2020-05-31")
df[, c("start","end") := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format="%Y-%m-%d"), .SDcols=c("start","end")]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution. First, the required packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
```

Write a function to create a vector of dates, 1 month apart, based on the start and end dates. Then convert those dates to numerical month, compare with the vector of numerical months and return the length:

```
find_overlap <- function(start_date, end_date, months) {
  seq.Date(start_date, end_date, "1 month") %>% 
    month() %>% 
    intersect(months) %>% 
    length()
}
```

Use `purrr::map` to apply the function to your data table:

```
v <- 5:10 # EDIT forgot to define this originally

df %>% 
  mutate(i = map2_int(start, end, ~find_overlap(.x, .y, v)))
```

Where there is no overlap, `i = 0`:

```
        start        end i
1  2018-06-01 2019-05-31 6
2  2018-06-04 2019-05-31 6
3  2018-06-05 2019-05-31 6
4  2018-07-20 2019-05-31 5
5  2018-11-01 2019-04-30 0
6  2019-01-01 2019-05-31 1
7  2019-04-01 2019-05-31 1
8  2019-05-01 2019-05-31 1
9  2019-06-01 2019-10-31 5
10 2019-06-01 2020-05-31 6
11 2019-11-01 2020-04-30 0
12 2020-05-01 2020-05-31 1
```

Then `filter` for cases where i is > 0 and optionally, remove the `i` column:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(i = map2_int(start, end, ~find_overlap(.x, .y, v))) %>%
  filter(i > 0) %>%
  select(-i)
```